# Filter data in Laravel using Laravel ORM hasmany & Vue 2

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, vuejs2

Excuse me, my using Laravel ORM hasmany with Vue 2.

Analysis Json data is some problems..

laravel ORM

```
$banner = Banner::with('banner_img')->get();
return response()->json($banner);
```

Json data

```
[{"id":10,"banner":"AIR","banner_img":[{"id":1,"img":"air_1.png","banner_id":10},{"id":2,"img":"air_2.png","banner_id":10}]},
{"id":11,"banner":"HOT","banner_img":[{"id":3,"img":"hot_1.png","banner_id":11},{"id":4,"img":"hot_2.png","banner_id":11}]},
{"id":12,"banner":"NEW","banner_img":[{"id":5,"img":"new_1.png","banner_id":12},{"id":6,"img":"new_2.png","banner_id":12}]}]
```

My json data have two array.

I want to filter this json data(banner_img:['img']) with Vue.js.

Vue.js

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    banner:[],
    search:'',
},
methods: {
    getBannerData: function() {
        axios.get('/case/ajax/33').then(response => {
            this.banner = response.data.banner;
        });
    },
},
mounted: function() {
   this.getBannerData();
},
computed: {
    filteredList() {
      return this.banner(value => {
        return value.banner.banner_img.img.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      })
    }
}
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="ImgFilter" v-model="search">
<div v-for="value in filteredList">
    <img v-for="imgs in value.banner_img" :src="imgs.img" height="100">
</div>
```

Then I try `return value.banner.banner_img.img` , but is wrong..

Please give me some advices～！  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your JSON example, each object  has an array of values on the property `banner_img`.  So `value.banner.banner_img.img` is incorrect because `value.banner` does not have property `banner_img`.

Try this:

```
filteredList() {
    return this.banner.filter(value => {
        return value.banner_img.filter(bannerImg => {
            return bannerImg.img.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks your reply! I try this it,very good! is get this data! but input search is not work...